# Same IDE for both C and Java projects?

Tags: eclipse

I have a Java project and a C project. I would like to use the Eclipse IDE to work on each project. To accomplish this I ended out downloading a version of ecliplse for C and a version for Java. Seems like I should only need 1 ide and then "switch perspectives" when I switch to work on a different project. However, the "Java" perspective is not available in the dropdown when the C version of eclipse is running, and vica-versa.

Do I really need two ides?

Answer (score 0):

Download one IDE. Go to the Eclipse Marketplace and install the other one. It will have both plugins installed for a single Eclipse IDE installation.

Answer (score 0):

No,

you can easily install the CDT features in a Java version of eclipse, or vice-versa, but I would add C++ to Java.

Once the features are installed the C++ projects can be opened and it is indistinguishable from the prepackaged version.

There is no magic there.

Help --> Install New Software --> Select helios repository (with a version indicator)

wait till the package list appears

Open the Programming Languages folder and select the CDT packages.

Typically eclipse complains so;e dependencies are missing, so select those too and it'll install.